# Video does not fire with chrome

Tags: php, internet-explorer, google-chrome, video

I have a problem with a video which does not fire with the chrome browser.

```
                <video width="560" height="315" id="video" onclick="enterFullscreen();" webkit-playsinline controls>
                    <source  src="/vid/making_of.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                </video>
```

Can anyone help me for this ? (it works as expected with IE)

Comment: which chrome version you are using???

Comment: Version 28.0.1500.95 m

Answer (score 2):

It might be a problem with the video encoding, Chrome does not support certain codecs.
More details [here](http://news.cnet.com/8301-30685_3-20028196-264.html).

If you need to solve this issue quickly use [JW Player](http://www.longtailvideo.com/jw-player/).